# AngularJS - Displaying data from API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, api, loops

I'm pretty new with AngularJS and have a problem with displaying data from an api call.

I want to display titles but I got stuck at some point. Could someone help me to loop through it?

Here is my [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3IkN.png)

**controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('appController', function($scope) {
    //console.log("test");
        var url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json";
        url += '?' + $.param({
          'api-key': "853fc084776f46e29732e71b3f1269ae"
        });
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          method: 'GET',
        }).done(function(result) {
          console.log(result);
          $scope.results = result;
        }).fail(function(err) {
          throw err;
        });
});
```

Here is my [json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN9R5.png)

Comment: Please post your json data so that i will know how to loop the data

Comment: json: enter image description here -> its here when you click on that link above

Comment: Upvote the answer bro :P am i need of reputation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was two problems you were facing first one is using jquery inside angular when angular has own http service you have used jquery ajax so the result variable wont be available for you on the html in the console it will print but you can't access in html so we have to write like below.

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.results = result.results;
});
```

Now to loop look at the below code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appController">
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="x in results">
     {{x.title}}
   <li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Working [codepen link](https://codepen.io/kannant14/pen/PjNPmz)

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you provided is an array of objects that in turn has an array of objects with a title.
So, you would need a nested array like below to display all titles in your JSON response.

```
<div ng-repeat="result in results">
  <div ng-repeat="child in result.results">
    {{child.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```